# Need help compiling in C

Tags: c, compilation

can someone help please?
i'm trying to compile in c but it gives me this error:

"error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

this is the part of the code

```
    if(anoc%4==0 && anoc%100!=0||anoc%400=0)
```

Comment: `anoc%400=0` -> `anoc%400==0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last part of the check, you are assigning the value 0 to anon%400. That is not possible.

```
anoc%400=0
```

You need to do:

```
anoc%400==0
```

EDIT — In future, please be more explanative about the type of variables you are using. As a good coding practice, use proper variable names. Good luck.

Comment: That is great. One thing I wish to point out —

`anoc=0` would have worked. It's an erroneous line of code but it would work as it is a valid assignment. This could have a lot of repercussions in your code.

But `anon%400` evaluates to a legal value; and it is not possible to assign to it. Therefore it gives you the lvalue error.

Answer (score 1):

You used a `=` instead of a `==`

```
if(anoc%4==0 && anoc%100!=0 || anoc%400==0)
```